# Group on Map value in hive

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, hiveql

I have a table in hive

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user
(
    name STRING,
    creation_date DATE,
    cards map<STRING,STRING>
) STORED AS PARQUET ;
```

Let's suppose that I want to query the number of Gobelin cards per user and group by them

My query looks like this :

```
 select card["Gobelin"], COUNT(*) from user GROUP BY card["Gobelin"] ;
```

I get an error on group by saying

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10033]: Line 54:30 [] not valid on non-collection types '"Gobelin"': string
```

Comment: Do you actually have a column named `card["Gobelin"]` ? In that case, try to change the name of that column.

Comment: @ChauLoi Yes, there is a column by that name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to count map elements with key `"Gobelin"`. You can explode the map, then filter out other keys and count the remaining values, e.g.

```
select count(*) as cnt
  from(select explode(cards) as (key, val) from table)
 where key = 'Gobelin'
```

You can use `lateral view` as well, see [Hive's manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) for details.